# Where should external DLL be located?

Tags: vb6, path

Let's say I have this at the top of a module:

```
Public Declare Function getCustomerDetails Lib "CustomerFunctions" () As Long
```

If I am running the program from the VB6 IDE, where should `CustomerFunctions.dll` be located?

If I am running the program executable, where should `CustomerFunctions.dll` be located?

Comment: most of the time dlls are placed in Systems folder.. C:/Windows/System32 for example..
and registered in the registry.

also check your references..

Comment: @PhilipBadilla: this is a third party DLL.

Comment: Yes but are you the one who referenced it?

Comment: @PhilipBadilla: Yes, I have been given the DLL and I want to reference it in module. Where do I put the DLL?  Which folder?

Comment: You can either just put it inside your application folder but its best if you put in in system folder so it wont get accidentally deleted..

Comment: @PhilipBadilla: What about when running from the IDE?  Does it have to go in the VB6 folder?

Comment: i was thinking of production that why was recommeding the systems folders.. the thing is just put it anywhere safe... a place where it should not change its directory...

Comment: @Philip: No, it's not best to put *anything* in the system folders unless it's a system file. A DLL that you create is most definitely *not* a system file. The system folder is not yours to mess with, that's why it's named "Windows" instead of "YourApp". Just put the DLL into your own application's folder, or if you have multiple apps sharing the DLL, put it into a common folder for your products in the "Program Files" folder. (Notice how that one is named "Program Files", implying that it's meant for files related to programs? That's you! A program!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When loading a standard DLL (rather than an ActiveX or COM dll), Windows applies the following rules;

If SafeDllSearchMode is turned on:

1. The Program directory.
2. The system directory.  Either (Windows\System32 or Windows\SysWow64 depending if you are running on 64 bit or not).
3. The 16-bit system directory (Windows\System).
4. The Windows directory.
5. The current directory.
6. All directories that in the PATH environment variable.

If SafeDllSearchMode is disabled, the search order is as follows:

1. The Program directory.
2. The current directory.
3. The system directory.  Either (Windows\System32 or Windows\SysWow64 depending if you are running on 64 bit or not).
4. The 16-bit system directory (Windows\System).
5. The Windows directory.
6. All directories that in the PATH environment variable.

My personal preference (rather than litter the System or Windows directory) is to create a developmentDLLs directory somewhere and add it to the [PATH](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519) variable.  When distributing the application place the DLL in the program's App directory.  This way you have the least chance of interferring with other DLL's.  For complete information on the loading of the DLL's see the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: +1. Neat idea to have an DLL dir on the path on your development pc

Comment: An executable can use a manifest to specify activation context even for standard DLLs e.g. `<file name="External\CustomerFunctions.dll">` will instruct `LoadLibraryExW` to search for  `CustomerFunctions.dll` only in `External` sub-folder under main executable folder. Also, if a file name contains (partial) path no search is done by `LoadLibrary` but simply fails.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is not an ActiveX DLL, somewhat different rules apply.

- When running in the IDE you could place it in either `c:\windows\system32` or in the directory from which VB6 is running (e.g. `c:\program files\microsoft visual studio...`).
- When running the program executable outside of VB6, you can place the DLL into either `c:\windows\system32` or the application directory.

Keep in mind that I gave you a technical answer (e.g. placing the file into `c:\windows\system32`), which will work.  However, the trend in the last decade has been to isolate the necessary components into the application directory.

Comment: I think "decade" is a conservative estimate... Windows XP is over a decade old, and it's been "trendy" not to litter the system folder(s) long before XP.

Comment: +1 The point being that when running in the VB6 IDE, it will not find the DLL in the "application directory" - the directory containing the VBP.